# How to use boolean with bootstrap nav-tabs?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use tabs instead of a `check_box`.

This is what I had...

`<%= f.check_box :someday %> Someday`

This is what I'm in the process of changing it to...

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="">Schedule</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="">Someday</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I do it so that when the Someday tab is clicked then it would be the equivalent of checked and Schedule would be the equivalent of unchecked?

Bootstrap is already integrated with project.

Comment: I don't think this is basically a good idea. I understand what you want to do, but I would keep the checkbox (but hide it) and use some JS/jQuery to read out the value and adapt the tabs accordingly. Ofcourse manually changing the tabs should then update the value of the checkbox as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view:

```
<li role="presentation"><a href="" id="someday_link">Someday</a></li>
<%= f.hidden_field :someday, value: "0", id: "someday_value" %>
```

In javascript/jquery:

```
$('#someday_link').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var checkbox_value = $('#someday_value').val();
  if (checkbox_value == "1") {
    $('#someday_value').val("0")
  } else {
    $('#someday_value').val("1")
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But when I click "Someday" the page just refreshes. Also what do I do with `<li role="presentation"><a href="">Schedule</a></li>`?

Comment: You might want to temporarily use `text_field` instead of `hidden_field` to see if the javascript is working correctly.